# Return the method after download is success

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am trying to download an image from the firebase storage and show the image after downloading it.
Is there any way to return my method only after the download complete?

here's the code of my method:

```
public void downloadImagesFromFireStorage(final String couponName, String imgName) {

    finish = false;

    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxx.appspot.com").child("imgs").child(imgName);

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {    
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            saveBitmap(couponName, bitmap);
        }
    });

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading..");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Now download " + couponName + "....");
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `OnCompleteListener`, to determine is task complete or not. For example,

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxx.appspot.com").child("imgs");
        final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<byte[]> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                      // do your work
                }
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

According to Firebase docs, `OnCompleteListener` called when a task completes. And it's public method `onComplete` return the completed task(never null). For example,

```
addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<byte[]> task) {
            //here, task is completed task returned by onComplete.
        }
    });
```

While, `OnSuccessListener` called when a task completes successfully. And it's method public method `onSuccess` returns the result of the task. For example,

```
addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
             //here, bytes are the result that you are downloading or uploading
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the different between OnSuccess and OnComplete?

Comment: oh, i see. what i really want to do is to do something outside the listener after the task has finished, because of what i write maybe need  to QwQ, not like this. But, thanks, i still learn a lot from this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but I'm not recommending it , you can add while loop to do nothing until `finish` flag changes to true , and you need to listen on `onFailure` to change `finish` flag

```
boolean finish;

public void downloadImagesFromFireStorage(final String couponName, String imgName) {


    finish = false;

    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxx.appspot.com").child("imgs").child(imgName);

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {    
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            saveBitmap(couponName, bitmap);
            finish = true;
        }
    });



    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading..");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Now download " + couponName + "....");
    progressDialog.show();

    while(!finish){/*DO NOTHING*/}

}
```

Comment: i need to refresh my imageView after the method called and complete (or says that image be downloaded), but if the download isn't complete, set the view well get nullexception, is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: also i call it several times to get a list of images and put them in listview, so i refresh them all in one method

Comment: to be sure , you want to display the image when download complete , right ?

Comment: well.. actually, what i am do is put the image into sqlite first and then retrieve it and display. Because of the sql execution, i have to write another method to do that. But yeah i want to do what you say :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a `SettableFuture` to return a `ListenableFuture`.

```
private ListenableFuture<Void> downloadImage() {
    final SettableFuture<Void> future = SettableFuture.create();

    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxx.appspot.com").child("imgs").child(imgName);

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    //performing the task on a background thread
    threadPoolService.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {    
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    saveBitmap(couponName, bitmap);
                    future.set(null);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return future;
}
```

And add a callback when the result is available.

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading..");
progressDialog.setMessage("Now download " + couponName + "....");
progressDialog.show();
Futures.addCallback(downloadImage(), new FutureCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@Nullable Void result) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Timber.e(t, "Error occurred while downloading image");
        }
    });
```

If you have several images to be downloaded, create a future for each of those images like,

```
List<SettableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for() {
  futures.add(downloadImage())
}
```

And then attach a callback when all the images are downloaded:

```
Futures.successfulAsList
```

Comment: I see, so the OnSuccess method will called when future set to null?
also if i write a method that use a for loop to call my downloadImage() several times, than put this method into Futures.addCallBack , will it call onSuccess when all the downloadImage complete? or i just need to do something else?

Comment: Have updated the answer for scenario where there is a list of images

Comment: to be sure, is the SettableFuture and Futures need to add something to the classpath? just like what Android Studio notice? but when i choose the options, nothing happens.

Comment: You will have to add a dependency for guava. `com.google.guava:guava:${GUAVA_VERSION}`

Comment: still cannot recognize SettableFuture
Android Studio told me to add "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core-2.2.2" to classpath (?)

Comment: the downloadimage method will return SettableFuture object and get compile error because cannot applied to ListenableFuture.
Also i'm a bit confuse about what to do, is that right to call Futures.successfulAsList and pass the list in? and still override onSuccess?